What are the characteristics of God's elect ? Is this how we will know that we are 'elect'?
I am not, here, inquiring about who the elect are or about how they are elected. There have been other questions about that and it seems to me there is no agreement on those matters.
But I am interested in the characteristics of the elect as someone has just asked me how anyone would know if they are one of what the bible calls 'God's elect'.
Jesus gives us some information about that :

And shall not God avenge his own elect, which cry day and night unto him, though he bear long with them? [Luke 18:7 KJV]

It seems that the elect cannot forbear from crying unto God in prayer. Not only can they not forbear for a twenty four hour period, they seem unable to last for even twelve hours without praying to Him.
Paul adds some more information about them :

Put on therefore, as the elect of God, holy and beloved, bowels of mercies, kindness, humbleness of mind, meekness, longsuffering; [Colossians 3:12 KJV]

Paul addresses the elect as 'holy and beloved'. He said of himself 'The Son of God who loved me and gave himself for me' so he, himself, knew he was loved by the Lord. So did John, calling himself 'the disciple whom Jesus loved'.
And they are 'holy'. Not only so, they are willing to have the apostle tell them to be even more so, with bowels of mercies, kindness, humility of mind, meekness and longsuffering : all characteristics displayed in regard to their fellow men. Not a matter of doing religious works to earn a reward from Deity, I notice.
And Paul gives more information :

Paul, a servant of God, and an apostle of Jesus Christ, according to the faith of God's elect, [Titus 1:1 KJV]


So is it the case that if someone is of these characteristics (prayerful, holy, beloved and believing) then they may be called 'one of God's elect'.
And is this how Paul was able, himself, to discern that some were, indeed, of God's elect, such as
those who received his preaching. And John, too, who calls someone 'the elect lady'.
Are these the characteristics which gave good reason for some to be singled out and addressed in that especial way as 'God's elect' ?
What other characteristics could be added to my brief research ?

This question is not scoped on the basis of a divide in doctrine. It is not aimed at one party or another. I am simply asking about characteristics and application.
But I am addressing Protestant Trinitarians, for the sake of simplicity and brevity.

See 2 Peter 1. It I think provides a good answer to your question. It’s not by statically possessing a list of qualities, but by demonstrating spiritual growth in Christlikeness and the fruit of the Spirit that we make “our calling and election sure” in contrast to as that passage discusses “being near-sided and blind”. If we decide “ok I’ve checked this this and this box so I’m good to rest on my laurels”, that is a heart antithetical to following Jesus by being lead by the Spirit and we should be concerned about whether we truly are born again and have the Spirit convicting & teaching us.

@bob If we are to 'make our calling and election sure' then there needs be certain parameters in order for us to do that. Hence my question. The concept of 'resting on laurels' has come from yourself, not I.

Sorry I didn’t mean you were suggesting we rest on our laurels. My point was that the answer whatever it be cannot be a static checklist per 2 Peter because of the emphasis on increasing measure. So I guess I’m suggesting that the question is a little askew and needs to be tweaked to exclude a static checklist. Also for a dynamic high level checklist 2 Peter works; you may find other characteristics in other verses elsewhere that add detail, but the general information that you seek is all there in that passage.

In other words 2 Peter 1 tells us how to make our calling and election sure.

The question asks whether the characteristics of prayerfulness, holiness, knowing they are beloved of God, and belief (in God and Christ) identifies ‘the elect of God’. And asks what other characteristics may point to that. Underlying this I see an unspoken issue, “Is every human on earth elect, so that we can all suppose that they are, and thus there is no need to look for identifying and distinguishing marks between them and any non-elect (the assumption being that there are none)?”
The first part of the question:  In addition to the biblical qualities already mentioned by the OP, the Bible also details humility, trembling at God’s word, seeking fellowship with other elect believers in a bond of love, worshipping God in spirit and in truth, avoiding idolatry (= false worship), being honest, loving their enemies and praying for them, and being prepared to die for Christ, their Saviour, rather than renounce him. It is not that the elect must demonstrate those qualities to a perfect degree. They cannot. The point is that there should be some clear, on-going evidence of their lives being transformed in those ways, because of the grace of God.
If anyone requires a list of Bible texts to substantiate that, I will provide it, but – really – every Christian ought to know the biblical grounds for such a list. Notice that I speak of Christians, and not all non-Christians. That is because many of the characteristics of non-Christians (even of some Christians) prove they cannot possibly be ‘the elect of God’. How could anyone who thinks nothing of lying, stealing, committing adultery, hating Christians, worshipping idols, and persecuting those who have faith in Christ ever be viewed as one of God’s elect? They would have to repent of all such sin and turn to Christ in faith before they could be considered as that. And, of course, many who formerly did such things have been transformed by God’s grace, renouncing those ways after being convicted by the Holy Spirit of their sin, of their offense before God.
The logical consequence of denying that there are identifying characteristics of God’s elect: This often surfaces in the claim that Jesus took our punishment and God does not punish twice. Ah, but the key question then becomes, Who form the ‘our’? Every created human, or only certain ones? The next step in that way of reasoning is that people become saved by grace once they choose to turn to Christ. Those who refuse to “choose Christ” will go into a state of annihilation at death – therefore, no punishment for living a life full of unrepented-of sin against God.
Those who hold to that view can become relaxed about eternal outcomes. They think they, and all others who have “chosen Christ” have completed a transaction. They chose. They are therefore now saved. They don’t have to worry about a few billion other people not showing evidence of God having saved them by grace, for at some stage before they die, they might “choose Christ”. No need to be concerned about other religions, for it will only be truly wicked people that will end up annihilated. Their choice. Shrug of shoulders (?) if only the truly wicked will not be saved, but they are not that, are they? They are good people, upstanding, law-abiding citizens. Romans chapter 3, verses 5-30, is not taken seriously. In part, it states that “Now we know that whatsoever the law says, it says to them who are under the law, that every mouth may be stopped, and all the world may become guilty before God. Therefore by the deeds of the law there shall no flesh be justified in his sight… For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God.”
A strange view often related to denying that there are identifying characteristics of God’s elect, is that law-abiding people who do good works must be pleasing to God, no matter what their religion, or lack of religion. This is strange (to the elect) because those who object to a sort-of-universal-election-bar-the-truly-wicked notion are turned on vehemently. That is due, in large measure, to a corrupted gospel throughout the world, that love is all that is needed to please God; be kind and loving and don’t criticize anyone, only talk about the love of God and never mention his wrath that is stored up for the awful day of Resurrection and Judgment.
Conclusion:  The Bible clearly says that one of the elect, the Apostle Paul, was not ashamed of the gospel, “For therein is the righteousness of God revealed from faith to faith: as it is written, The just shall live by faith. For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who hold the truth in unrighteousness; …so that they are without excuse.” Romans 1:16-20 A.V.
To effectively accuse God of unrighteousness because he will pour his wrath upon those who ‘hold the truth in unrighteousness,’ is an evident characteristic of those who are not God’s elect.

Rom 5:6-9 "For when we were yet without strength, in due time Christ died for the ungodly. 7 For scarcely for a righteous man will one die: yet peradventure for a good man some would even dare to die.
8 But God commendeth his love toward us, in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us. 9 Much more then, being now justified by his blood, we shall be saved from wrath through him."  2 Cor 11:3 "But I fear, lest by any means, as the serpent beguiled Eve through his subtilty, so your minds should be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ."

I believe that Paul's internal battle of knowing the difference between what is right and wrong, but struggling in finding the way "to perform that which is good" (Rom 7:18) is a characteristic that every Christian experiences.
There are plenty of unbelievers who do "good", and there are also Satan's "ministers of righteousness" (2 Cor 11:15) that keep lost souls focused on their own self-righteous works (efforts) in hopes of pleasing God.  What both of these groups lack is the recognition of the righteousness of God through Christ crucified for them (Rom 10:1-4).
Although it is the "reasonable service" for an "elect" of God to present themselves holy (Rom 12:2), they will most likely fail at times in their calling, as they are still trapped in their corruptible body of flesh until death (1 Cor 15:53).  The spiritual gift that a true believer has is the ability of looking to Christ and the cross as their reminder and strength in overcomimg their battle going forward. They are reminded that their iniquites were all paid for through Christ's shed blood for the very purpose of their failures.
One can rest with certainty knowing they are one of God's elect if they have this faith in Christ and a desire to thank God always for the purchase that Christ alone paid on their behalf because of His love for them.
Romans 3:25

Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;

1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:


You seem to be suggesting that Christians just keep failing all the time and never, in your account, achieve any consistency. If faith does not result in consistent behaviour I wonder if it can be called 'the faith of God's elect'. And, on the other hand, you suggest that unbelievers can 'do good' which I do not find in my bible. Also, Romans 7 is Paul's experience prior to finding deliverance, not in Christian maturity.

Well a couple of examples that come readily to mind - Darius in Isaiah 44 (bringing the people of God back from exile) and the Good Samartian.

@NigelJ The faith of God's elect is about having faith in Christ, not faith in their own self-righteous "consistent behavior" (filthy rags).  If Paul, In Rom 7, is prior to coversion, explain verse 25: "I thank God through Jesus Christ our Lord. So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin."  Also, don't forget about the Corinthian and his mother-in-law.  Cast out of the Corinthian church, but didn't lose salvation.  Paul is consistently admonishing his audience to "put away the old man" and live more righteously for God, NOW that they are His adopted.

@NigelJ, yes non-believers can do more good than Christians. I have experienced it personally where a friend of mine from Italy indiscriminately helped people who had children in need of tenotomy procedures et cetera. He was a scientific atheist who helped more than any other Christian I have ever seen.

Paul says to the Thessalonians, "we know, brothers loved by God, that he has chosen you, because our gospel came to you not simply with words, but also with power, with the Holy Spirit and with deep conviction. You know how we lived among you for your sake. You became imitators of us and of the Lord; in spite of severe suffering, you welcomed the message with the joy given by the Holy Spirit. And so you became a model to all the believers in Macedonia and Achaia. The Lord’s message rang out from you not only in Macedonia and Achaia— your faith in God has become known everywhere. Therefore we do not need to say anything about it, for they themselves report what kind of reception you gave us. They tell how you turned to God from idols to serve the living and true God, and to wait for his Son from heaven, whom he raised from the dead— Jesus, who rescues us from the coming wrath. 1Th 1:4-10
So here Paul lists evidences of their election.
They received the message with joy, though that itself is not solid evidence as we learn in the parable of sower that "The one who received the seed that fell on rocky places is the man who hears the word and at once receives it with joy. But since he has no root, he lasts only a short time. When trouble or persecution comes because of the word, he quickly falls away." Mt 13:20,21 However he mentioned it was received with joy in the midst of severe suffering, which qualified their joy to be genuine and born of conviction.
Another is they became imitators of Paul and of the LORD, which can't be said of many a Christian today.
And thirdly they were involved in Evangelism, which also can't be said of many Christians today whose Christian lives are limited to church attendance.
They repented from their sinful lifestyle and lived to served Christ.
Noteworthy is the fact that Paul didn't mention water baptism, a mere religious ceremony performed among Christians requiring little effort and thus hardly an indicator of true faith.
Another such passage is 1John 3:9,10 "No one who is born of God will continue to sin, because God’s seed remains in him; he cannot go on sinning, because he has been born of God. This is how we know who the children of God are and who the children of the devil are: Anyone who does not do what is right is not a child of God; nor is anyone who does not love his brother."
So, not sinning, but characteristically doing what is right is an indicator. This in contrast to the many lists of those going to hell such as 1Cor 6:9,10; Rev 21:8; Gal 5:19-21
And the love of the brethren, of which Jesus also affirmed saying, "By this all men will know that you are my disciples, if you love one another." John 13:35

"Noteworthy is … baptism … hardly an indicator of true faith" — Many things are not indicators of true faith, so why spoil your answer by inserting this one not noteworthy comment? It's irrelevant to the question, adds nothing useful to the answer, and is guaranteed to cause some people to reject the whole answer because of this one blemish.

@BCBSR Thank you for giving a very good example of what both Paul and Peter clarify to be something that dininishes the effect of the cross. 1 Corinthians 1:17 "For Christ sent me not to baptize, but to preach the gospel: not with wisdom of words, lest the cross of Christ should be made of none effect." 1 Peter 3:21 "The like figure whereunto even baptism doth also now save us (not the putting away of the filth of the flesh, but the answer of a good conscience toward God,) by the resurrection of Jesus Christ:" +1

2 Peter 1:3-11 provides a good answer to your question:

3His divine power has granted to us all things that pertain to life and godliness, through the knowledge of him who called us to his own glory and excellence, 4by which he has granted to us his precious and very great promises, so that through them you may become partakers of the divine nature, having escaped from the corruption that is in the world because of sinful desire. 5For this very reason, make every effort to supplement your faith with virtue, and virtue with knowledge, 6and knowledge with self-control, and self-control with steadfastness, and steadfastness with godliness, 7and godliness with brotherly affection, and brotherly affection with love. 8For if these qualities are yours and are increasing, they keep you from being ineffective or unfruitful in the knowledge of our Lord Jesus Christ. 9For whoever lacks these qualities is so nearsighted that he is blind, having forgotten that he was cleansed from his former sins. 10Therefore, brothers, be all the more diligent to confirm your calling and election, for if you practice these qualities you will never fall. 11For in this way there will be richly provided for you an entrance into the eternal kingdom of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ.

It’s not by statically possessing a list of qualities that we demonstrate ourselves to be elect (“For if these qualities are yours and are increasing”), but by demonstrating spiritual growth in Christlikeness (“supplement your faith with virtue, and virtue with knowledge, 6and knowledge with self-control…”) and the fruit of the Spirit that we “confirm your calling and election” in contrast to as that passage discusses being “so nearsighted that he is blind” and in danger of falling-not entering eternal life after all because we have deceived ourselves. If we decide ok I’ve checked this and this and this box so I’m good to rest on my laurels, that is a heart antithetical to following Jesus by being lead by the Spirit (see how the passage opens talking about how our ability to grow in maturity comes from God’s divine power. While we participate actively in God’s work in and through us, it’s not simply human effort) and we should be concerned about whether we truly are born again and have the Spirit convicting and teaching us.
